# Possible from android app to post pic,text and url in the same post to FB wall?

Tags: android

Is it possible from an android app to post a little picture, an url , and text in the same post to the facebook wall of the person that plays the app? Like "share"....  or is it only allowed to post one of them? Some similar posts are old so not sure what facebook allows us today

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Take a look at the Facebook api documentation which can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/post